# How to get message to user from before_validate in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code which makes sure no user is using the system as spam bot.  In the model ShopInvite I have this code:

```
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    !(ShopInvite.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.ago(60.minutes)).where(:sender_ip => self.sender_ip).count > 2)
  end
```

This works but how do I get the message 'Not send due to spam protection' into the view?

Comment: Can you post your controller code that relies on this validation? You could use the `valid?` method in the object instance (in the controller) to pass the message into the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an error to your instance:

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  if (ShopInvite.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.ago(60.minutes)).where(:sender_ip =>  self.sender_ip).count > 2)
    errors[:base] << 'cannot be sent due to spam protection'
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Then, as d_ethier said, you call the `valid?` method on the instance, and if it returns false you show the error message on the view.

Though this is actually a kind of validation, so you should probably do this with `validates` instead of `before_validation`.

Comment: Note, though, like any `before` callback, it will halt execution if and only if it returns false. As such, this definition is functionally _different_ than the original, returning something "non-false" in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you want.
Becareful that validate by custom method is plural **validate**

```
class ShopInvite < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :message_to_user

def message_to_user

 if (ShopInvite.where("created_at >= ?", Time.now.ago(60.minutes)).
     where(:sender_ip => self.sender_ip).count > 2)
     errors[:base] << 'cannot be sent due to spam protection'
     false
  else
    true
  end
end
end
```